# How do I configure geofencing?

Tags: geofencing, toloka

do you guys know how to configure geofencing in Toloka? I know that there are templates for such spatial tasks but I need some tips on the configuration itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Everyone who creates a task can flexibly customize the template, write their own js code, and set up the photo and coordinate verification process in their own way. You can use a typical template for field tasks as a basis.
You need to add the following parameters to file-img (https://yandex.ru/support/toloka-requester/concepts/t-components/upload-picture.html):

- Image data must contain coordinates. requiredCoordinates=true — Coordinates are mandatory.
- compress=false — Render the image without changes or compression (because your instructions require "Resolution of at least 6 megapixels (3000x2000 pix or similar)".
  You can also add your own js code which will check, for example, the distance between the performer and your location.